# UITableView Edit Mode by default

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch, ipad

I am trying to have a tableView which have edit button to remove cells by default. Is there anyway to achieve that rather than selecting edit button and then to get to edit mode?

Thanks

Answer (score 4):

Editing mode is a state of the `UITableView`. You can set it programmatically with:

```
[tableView setEditing:YES animated:YES]
```

You can do this anytime, with or without animation.

Answer (score 1):

Set the table view to editing mode as soon as it appears. In your viewWillAppear method:

```
self.tableView.editing = YES;
```